# Shortcut in IntelliJ equivalent to Ctrl + Shift + G

Tags: eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

I want to search for a list of references on one method or class in IntelliJ. Is there any shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in Eclipse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is my favorite key combination for finding usages as it gives you a nice popup with good interaction.

Otherwise you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> that will show you the same information in a tool window at the bottom that will stay there.

Look at the the [Default Keymap Reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keymap-reference.html) in the Help menu for all the built-in shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: I agree @maba has the best answer here, and I like the popup mentioned above. One thing I'd add for the Alt+F7 approach is that you can scroll up and down through the results without leaving the keyboard: Ctrl+Alt+↑ (Up Arrow) and Ctrl+Alt+↓ (Down Arrow)

Answer (score 1):

for searching name of methods in whole project use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

for searching classes (Files)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>     Find usages in file that is, to find all places where a particular class, method or variable is used in the whole project in intellij IDEA